# How do payments matching against invoices/vendor bills in odoo15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

Can you provide an idea about about invoice/vendor bills payments allocation .
I am using odoo15 . In payments i added a one2many for list customers' not fully paid invoices/vendor bills .
I need to allocate partial/ full payment when post payments .

Here is my code .

class AccountPayment(models.Model):

```
_inherit = "account.payment"

payment_line_ids = fields.One2many('account.payment.line', 'payment_id', string="Invoice Adjustment")

@api.onchange('partner_id')
def _onchange_partner_id(self):
    line_vals = []
    for rec in self:
        rec.payment_line_ids = False
        if rec.partner_id:
            partner_moves = self.env['account.move'].search([('partner_id', '=', rec.partner_id.id),('state', '=', 'posted'), ('payment_state', 'in',('not_paid','partial'))])

            for mov in partner_moves:
                open_invoice_lines = {
                    'move_id':mov.id,
                    'date':mov.date,
                    'date_due': mov.invoice_date_due,
                    'original_amount': mov.amount_total,
                    'balance_amount': mov.amount_residual,
                    'payment_id':rec.id,
                }
                line_vals.append((0, 0, open_invoice_lines))
        rec.payment_line_ids = line_vals
```

class AccountPaymentLine(models.Model):

```
_name = 'account.payment.line'

payment_id = fields.Many2one('account.payment')
move_id = fields.Many2one('account.move', string="Invoices/Bills")
date = fields.Date(string="Date")
date_due = fields.Date(string="Due Date")
original_amount = fields.Float(string="Original Amount")
balance_amount = fields.Float(string="Balance Amount")
allocation_amount = fields.Float(string="Allocation Amount")
```

[image]

Comment: What about Batch Payments? You will have one payment per invoice/bill, but put them into a batch. On reconciliation with for example a bank statement, Odoo will "split" the payment with one click. See [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/applications/finance/accounting/payments/batch.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank for info. Batch payments are not work in my case because in my case need to map amount to multiple invoices / bills . some cases need to pay partial amount .